# Где можно взять дистрибутивы под ubuntu и как их грамотно ставить?

Tags: ubuntu

Я хочу сохранять дистрибутивы различных программ под ubuntu, чтобы можно было хранить на флешке и устанавливать на компьютер, не имеющий доступ к интернету.
Например, мне нужна утилита make, ide vs code и т.д.
Как это можно сделать?

Comment: См. например: [Как скачать deb-пакет со всеми зависимостями без его установки](https://linuxthebest.net/kak-skachat-deb-paket-so-vsemi-zavisimos/)